# Eclipse setting for generating getters and setters insertion point last member

Tags: eclipse, generator, setter, getter

It really annoys me already now... I can not find the setting to have by default insertion point at last member.

Why? Generating getters and setters would then be:
ALT+SHIFT+S -> space, space, space... -> ENTER :)

And not like now:
ALT+SHIFT+S -> space, space, space... -> tab, tab, tab, tab, tab, -> up, up, up... -> ENTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to with Europa it used to remember the last setting of insertion point. But since Ganymede it defaults to 'After xxx' all the time. As far I can't seem to find any setting to change this behaviour. Right how I just do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of class and then do the generation.

Consider downgrading or reporting a [bug](http://bugs.eclipse.org).

Comment: !"#$#$%&/&%$
Ok, I reported the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295281

Let see what will happen.

Comment: Downgrade is not an option :)